# How to get directions from two sets of coordinates using google api in java

Tags: java, google-maps

Can't really find anything. But I am writing a javafx project where the user inputs latitude/longitude and get returned with directions. I am looking for concrete examples to do this. I  know I have to send have a specific url from google api. But I have no clue how to use the url and get the json format back and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use request parameters including the origin and destination in [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) and you should be able to get directions.

Comment: how do i make the request in java?

Comment: They have their own java api there once you bring it into your project you can call up the method to set the origin and destination

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Map's Web API

Here's the documentation for it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API provides a direction API, this gives a set a directions between two points.

Here's an example with using a JSON response, you can also use XML as documented in the API: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=37.421957,-122.084197&destination=37.431865,-122.103789

See this for full reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

Comment: I have zero experience in api's. Could you give me an example on how the call to the google maps api is made and returned?

Comment: Well, this API simply provides you with a JSON response of all the directions and all you _need_ to give it is the `origin` and `destination`. So I am assuming you want some Java context here. If you want to deal with JSON responses you can use the `org.json` library to process the response but to make a `get` request you can use `java.net.URL` and then do something like `URL(url).openStream()` and read the JSON using `Scanner` and then `JSONObject` to read the returned JSON response from the API. I would go with what @J-Dominator suggested.